# Declined flag for low-quality question

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I recently had a flag declined for flagging a low-quality question and now I'm getting warnings when I try to flag other questions. This question looks blatantly terrible to me but the comment says:

```
declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it
```

Is this considered a satisfactory question?

Question can be found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324164/metasploit-error-starting-msfconsole-mac-os-x)

I just recovered from a 2 week review ban over an honest mistake and now I'm hyper-paranoid about making the wrong move on anything, so I'd like to know how/why this is a good question.

Comment: Sure the question is bad, but should it really be on a mod's plate? Just flag as close->unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I didn't flag it for moderator review, I thought regular users could have a question closed without mods.

Comment: If you want a question closed without mods, cast a flag "this question should be closed", providing a reason. This is exactly what that category of flags is for.

Comment: Is that not what I did? I flagged it as low quality, but now that option isn't even showing up so I don't recall if it was under the close sub-menu or part of the parent menu.

Comment: No, this is not what you did. "Very low quality" is a separate category; I could go on describing it but I won't, because the criteria for VLQ are currently under reform. Just take my advice: if you want a question closed, give a specific reason why it should be closed. "Low Quality" is not cutting it.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I should go read up on that because I thought flagging for mod attention was the only way to bother mods with flags. I thought the rest of them went to users with more privileges.